# Messed up topology: Do I need to fix it?

Tags: vertices, edges, faces, topology, retopology

[image]

I was trying to connect the neck to the body after I tried to model the neck bones on my model. However, the no. of edges of the torso were greater than that of the neck so I messed up with the connection! All my edge loops are ruined!

So the question is, will this topology be a problem when I rigify my model? Or can I just sweep it under the rug?

Here's my blend file:

https://filebin.net/vz6i8k4prtmde8fb/tutorial_demo.blend

Comment: you should redo the neck from scratch, it will probably be easier

Answer (score 1):

She will deform a lot more smoothly if the edge flow is more consistent. You can select all the neck geometry, press p to separate into another object, and model around it starting from the last loop of good typology.

Comment: However, if the character will be wearing a shirt that covers the typology or will only be seen from far out. Then it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, all you have to do is look at it.  Does this look okay?

[image]

I don't think that looks great for the poly count myself.  But, the issue is much the shape as the topo.  I've separated out a cross section so you can see that the shape isn't as smooth as it could be, even disregarding topology.  (Generally, using as few vertices as possible is the ideal way to get the smoothest geometry, and I'd say that this neck has more vertices than it needs to provide the level of detail that it's going for.)

Now, animation can complicate things, so if this happens to be good enough for you, will it still be good enough once you rig it?  Your topology needs to be good enough to support the deformations you want-- if something is smooth at rest but is going to deformed into a ridge, you still want edge flow that supports that ridge; if a star is planar at rest, it's still going to be a problem if it gets deformed out of plane by your armature.  But in the case of Rigify, it doesn't really do anything with the neck tendons, so overall, deformation with Rigify alone isn't going to make this any worse than it is at rest.  So if the rest mesh is good enough for you, the Rigify version should be as well.

Comment: "this neck has more vertices than it needs to provide the level of detail that it's going for"- however, if I change the number of vertices on the neck(where I'd later bridge the head), I won't be able to attach the head later(as it's cross section has 27 edges, I started high-poly). So I can't help it.

Comment: @MsBonniePython Maybe make a neck however you want, and shrinkwrap your final topo onto it?